# Import SQL file into Rails database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, import

I want to import a .sql file so that my new schema and datas is the one and the .sql file (so I don't care about losing my current schema and datas)

I tried `rails db < sql-file-path` but it returns me an error :

[image]

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562269/6727266) but it's not clear what this is really doing, like we have to create a migration to execute ruby code and import a file ? 
Every solution is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need do necessarily  with rails. You can use only mysql if you're comfortable with it. You can access mysql console by:

```
mysql -u user_name -p
```

Exchange "user_name" by your user (root for example), then it will ask for your user password.
When you have access to the console, you can select your development database by:

```
use your_database_name;
```

and then, to import:

```
source your_sql_file.sql
```

You can check your credentials and your database name on your `database.yml`.

If it doesn't work, please check your sql syntax or try to generate the dump file again.

Good luck, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would follow these steps:

1. Backup your database
2. Run the script
3. Create Rails models for any new tables you imported
4. Recreate the schema.rb file from the database

   `bundle exec rake db:schema:dump`